# html elements load after Javascript file even though the <script> tag is at the bottom of the <body> tag

Tags: javascript, html

I got a Javascript problem. The HTML elements keep waiting for the javascript file, even though the script tag is at the bottom of the page. Elements do not update if changed and disappear after 5 seconds This is the code:
[image]

code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Javascript</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>javascript in HTML</h1>
    <p>HElllllooooo</p>




    <script type="text/javascript">
        var age  = prompt("What is your age?");

        if (Number(age) < 18) {
            alert("Sorry, you are too young to drive this car. Powering off ");
        } else if (Number(age) > 18) {
            alert("Powering on. Enjoy the ride!");
        } else if (Number(age) === 18 ) {
            alert("Congratulations on your first year of driving. Enjoy the 
                  ride!"); 
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Post code instead of picture

Comment: Your Javascript being at the end of the page does secure that all the HTML is already ***parsed*** before your JS runs. It does not secure that the HTML is ***rendered***.

Answer (score 1):

`prompt` is synchronous, and hence blocks execution until it returns. That's why the second line (and the rest of the lines) don't execute until your `prompt` returns.

As for the `script` tag being at the bottom, enforce it like this:

```
window.onload = myFunction
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add it inside of its own anonymous function which can be set to run `onload`;

That in theory should work fine:

```
(function () {
  var age = prompt("What is your age?");

  if (Number(age) < 18) {
    alert("...");
  } else if (Number(age) > 18) {
    alert("...");
  } else if (Number(age) === 18) {
    alert("...");
  } else {
    // ... fallback logic?
  }
})();
```

Or as it has been answered, you may want to wrap the code inside of a `window.load` var. Also an anonymous function.

Answer (score 0):

Just simply add an `onload` attribute on the `<body>` like so, whatever:

```html
<body onload="carsGoBrr()">
```

And then **DEFINE** the function:

```js
function carsGoBrr() {
  var age = prompt("What is your age?");

  if (Number(age) < 18) {
    alert("Sorry, you are too young to drive this car. Powering off ");
  } else if (Number(age) > 18) {
    alert("Powering on. Enjoy the ride!");
  } else if (Number(age) === 18 ) {
     alert("Congratulations on your first year of driving. Enjoy the ride!"); 
  }
}
```

### FULL CODE ( By my style of coding ;) ):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Javascript</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>javascript in HTML</h1>
    <p>HElllllooooo</p>
    <script>
      function carsGoBrr() {
        var age = prompt("What is your age?");

        if (Number(age) < 18) {
          alert("Sorry, you are too young to drive this car. Powering off ");
        } else if (Number(age) > 18) {
          alert("Powering on. Enjoy the ride!");
        } else if (Number(age) === 18 ) {
          alert("Congratulations on your first year of driving. Enjoy the ride!"); 
        }
      }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried placing your conditional into a window.onload function?

```
window.onload = function(){
    // code goes here
};
```